# ubuntu apache2 mod_proxy replace internal url's

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, mod-proxy

I've followed every guide I can find on Google and still cant solve this!

I've managed to set up mod_proxy to pull back an internal website, but the website adds internal links to menu items which wont work for external users, so Im trying to rewrite them from `.int` domains to `.com` domains.

I have the following virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.itmanx.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    #ProxyHTMLInterp On     #used to be ProxyHTMLEnable
    #ProxyHTMLExtended On   #will parse all scripts and css files as well [slow if on]

    ProxyPass / http://shop.itmanx.int/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://shop.itmanx.int/
    #ProxyHTMLURLMap / /test/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap (.*)itmanx.int(.*) $1itmanx.com$2 [Rin]

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have made sure the components are loaded

```
[Sun Jan 29 14:59:46 2012] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sun Jan 29 14:59:46 2012] [warn] module proxy_http_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sun Jan 29 14:59:46 2012] [warn] module proxy_html_module is already loaded, skipping
```

but no links are altered. So what am i missing?

The server is Ubuntu Server 11.10

Answer (score 1):

Huzzah!!!  Thanks to the guys at [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Running+Hudson+behind+Apache) who quoted the following:

> Because hudson already compress its output, you can not use the normal
>   proxy-html filter to modify urls:`
>
> **SetOutputFilter proxy-html**
>
> Instead you can use the following:
>
> **SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE;**

and because of this one line, it's now working

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.itmanx.com
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

    ProxyPass / http://shop.itmanx.int/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://shop.itmanx.int/
    ProxyRequests Off

    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE;
    ProxyHTMLURLMap (.*)itmanx.int(.*) $1itmanx.com$2 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```